# OnBlur after OnFocus calls method

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am currently working with a set of textboxes in a grid that represent days of the week. There is also a drop down list (with its selected index) that also shows the dates for the week. Also there is a text area that represents specific comments for each day of the chosen week as well.

When focusing, either with clicks or TAB, my Javascript function calls out the server side method (C#) for the selected index change method of the data drop down. Each day passes its index back to the function, then runs the SelectedIndexChanged method.

This way when I click on a week day, I can show the comments and change the date drop down, rather than have to resort to using the drop down.

I did this by adding the attributes like so:

```
gridTextBox.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "changeSelectedDayComments(" + index.ToString() + ")");
```

All that said, the issue I'm facing is when I try to enter text in a cell, flicker occurs and deletes my text. Is there a corresponding way of adding attribute for onBlur after using onFocus to call to a method, using Javascript only? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to call onBlur?

Comment: Figured since onFocus is being used to call the function, then onBlur would allow focus to be taken off of the current grid text box when moving to the next focused grid text box

Comment: The issue was in the called function itself. Accidentally used datelist.onChange rather than dateList.onFocus, so each time i switched grid text boxes and tried to change the text, I was recalling the function each time, thus the "flicker" as well. Runs just fine now. Thanks IvanJ

Answer (score 0):

I had to revisit the Javascript function being used.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function changeSelectedDayComments(index) {
    //cast as drop down and set the index
    index = index - 5; //where the first day is listed in grid/match date drop down
    var dateList = document.getElementById("Dropdown_CommentsDateSelection");
    dateList.selectedIndex = index;
    //call back to event to fire upon change
    setTimeout(function() {
        dateList.onfocus(function () { 
            Dropdown_CommentsDateSelection_SelectedIndexChanged()
        });
    }, 1);
}
</script>
```

As mentioned, dateList.onChange rather than dateList.onFocus was the issue.